# Are piecewise continuous functions locally integrable?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I known that continuity implies local integrability. Is this valid for piecewise continuous functions?

Comment: Would you say that $$x \mapsto \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x} & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } x = 0 \end{cases}$$ is piecewise continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the functions is integrable on any compact subset of the domain which makes it locally intetrable.

We simply integrate on the intervals where the function is continuous and add the results using the formula $$ \int _a ^c f(x)dx = \int _a ^b f(x)dx +\int _b ^c f(x)dx$$

Comment: Isn't integrable stronger than locally integrable?

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik  On the contrary, integrable functions are locally integrable, but locally integrable functions are not necessarily globally integrable. Please refer to the definition of locally  integrable functions.